# Combining two ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to combine two ranges into one variable. Here is my code but not sure why I am getting *Type Mismatch* error 13:

```
Dim rngText as Range, rngText2 as Range, dText
Set rngText = wSheet3.Range(wSheet3.Range("A1"), wSheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
Set rngText2 = wSheet3.Range(wSheet3.Range("B1"), wSheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

'this line I am getting an error:
dText = rngText.Value & rngText2.Value
```

Comment: Either `rngText.Value` or `rngText2.Value` contains an error. Errors can't be compared to or concatenated with strings. Always validate your inputs!

Comment: also  you cannot concatenate multiple cell ranges like that.  You would need to loop through the range concatenating each cell.

Comment: Ya, i can't concatenate array. So How do I do it then??

Comment: load both into arrays, loop through the arrays concatenating in the order you wish.

Comment: @ScottCraner oh wow, didn't even bother looking at what they were `Set` to lol... indeed, these would be arrays... which aren't strings. Still validate the inputs, because if any cell contains an error, you'll get that exact same error.

Comment: The answer in the linked question should get you started. Note that it doesn't validate the cell values with `IsError` before concatenating them, which is error-prone.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I guess you marked it as duplicate which is not. I am using array and other one using string. Plus i can't use loop, its going to make my program slow i am dealing with 18million rows.

Comment: You **have** to use loops. Arrays don't just concatenate themselves. `&` is an operator that works with `String` operands: if you mean to output a `String` as the result (which is exactly what your code looks like), then this **is** a duplicate, read the answer again - it's working with a 2D array, so you feed it with `Union(rngText, rngText2)` and it gives you your string, with the separator you want. If that's not exactly what you need, then your question is unclear and should be closed as such anyway.

Comment: @Mat'sMug dText which is a variant, im not using string variable.

Comment: `dText` is a variant assigned using a string expression (that's what `&` makes it be), therefore it's a `Variant/String`, or *would be* if the assignment was legal (not to mention d**Text** has all looks of a string - use meaningful names that say what they mean and mean what they say). If your question isn't a dupe then by all means [edit] it to clarify exactly what you mean by "concatenate", because that's not it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug when you define a string, you have to write string at the end, if you don't define it, it's automatically assigned by variant. Check it out online before you start debating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164127/discussion-between-mats-mug-and-user3713336).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `&` concatenation operator works with `String` operands, and you're giving it two 2D Variant arrays containing the values of an unknown number of cells.

You can't use `&` to combine `Range` objects like this; the *type mismatch* is because VBA is expecting `String` operands to the `&` operator, therefore resolving the expression to a `String`.

Instead, use the `Application.Union` function - that function will take your `rngText` and `rngText2` ranges as arguments, *union* them, and return a single `Range` object that includes the two. Because a `Range` is an object type, you'll need to use the `Set` keyword for that assignment:

```
Set dText = Union(rngText, rngText2)
```

There's not really a reason to not declare `dText As Range` now :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I got lost in live chat and couldn't follow up but Thanks a lot.

Comment: it's only counting one range somehow its not counting other range

Comment: @user3713336 I don't see any code counting anything. If you have a new question, *ask* a new question! :)

Comment: I did it but not sure my title is understandable or not. Let me know if you have any question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527096/looping-through-two-ranges-in-one-variant-variable