# Looping through two ranges in one variant variable

Tags: vba, excel

Looping through two ranges in one variant variable.

I am trying to read two ranges together at the same time using one variant. I have two ranges A and B, and I am combining them. After combining these two ranges, I am using a variant to read it. My variant variable only reading column A and ignoring Column B. Any suggestion what I am doing wrong.

```
Dim rngText as Range, rngText2 as Range, results as Range, dText
   Set rngText = wSheet3.Range(wSheet3.Range("A1"), wSheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
   Set rngText2 = wSheet3.Range(wSheet3.Range("B1"), wSheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
   Set results = Union(rngText, rngText2)
   dText = results.Value

        For i = 1 to Ubound(dText,1)
          'other condition here.... 

        Next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> For i = 1 to Ubound(dText,1)
> ```

This loop iterates the first dimension of `dText`, which is declared as an implicit `Variant`.

> ```
> dText = results.Value
> ```

This assigns the `Variant` with a 2D array representing the result of the `Union` operation. Unless a `Range` is representing a single cell, `Range.Value` always returns a 2D array.

You need a nested loop to iterate both dimensions of your 2D array.

```
Dim currentRow As Long
For currentRow = 1 To UBound(dText, 1)
    Dim currentCol As Long
    For currentCol = 1 To UBound(dText, 2)
        ' do stuff
    Next
Next
```

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, it might be better to only iterate rows, and have your loop body's logic get the column indices:

```
Dim currentRow As Long
For currentRow = 1 To UBound(dText, 1)
    Debug.Print "Column A: " & dText(currentRow, 1), "Column B: " & dText(currentRow, 2)
Next
```

Note that the 2D array holds `Variant` values representing whatever value/type that's held in the cells: if a cell contains a number, the array index will point to some `Variant/Double`; if a cell contains a string, the array index will point to some `Variant/String`; if a cell contains an error, the array index will point to some `Variant/Error` - and that last point is critical: you'll want to validate that the cell value doesn't contain an error before you assume its type and do anything with it (e.g. the above string-concatenation would fail with run-time error 13 / "type mismatch" given a `Variant/Error` value in either column, because a `String` can't be compared to or otherwise converted [implicitly or explicitly] to an `Error`). This would be safer:

```
Dim currentRow As Long
For currentRow = 1 To UBound(dText, 1)
    If Not IsError(dText(currentRow, 1) And Not IsError(dText(currentRow, 2)) Then
        Debug.Print "Column A: " & dText(currentRow, 1), "Column B: " & dText(currentRow, 2)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: This is a diversion but do you generally prefer to declare variables as you use them rather than grouping the declarations at the top?

Comment: @SJR yes. all the time. always. consistently. declare variables where they're used - defeats pseudo-hungarian prefixing's alleged purpose =)

Comment: Thanks. Does it make a difference to performance or do you just regard it as better practice?  (I tend to do the other as that is how I have mostly seen it done.)

Comment: @SJR `Dim` statements aren't executable, there's no difference whatsoever in terms of performance. This is all about readability: declaring variables as close as possible to their usage is a widespread best practice in any modern language, I'm failing to see why VBA would have to be stuck in 1990's practices.

Comment: not to mention a "wall of declarations" at the top of a long procedure makes for especially painful maintenance (constant scrolling back & forth - been there, done that - no thanks), and consistently results in dead/unused variables in any non-trivial code.

Comment: Yes good point about the scrolling. Have your work cut out though - I rarely see code written this way.

Comment: I am using another loops cause can't use &. I thought if i can use without defining any other loops

Comment: @user3713336 I don't know what that means. Please re-read the answer; note that the `Debug.Print` statement is just a placeholder for `' do stuff`, it just outputs the values to the *immediate pane*, while illustrating how you can access values from both dimensions of the array in a single loop.

Comment: @Mat'sMug i edited my question and added more code. I do get an error Subscript out of range on my second loop (Rune time error 9) I don't know why

Comment: @user3713336 that's again a completely different question, and now my answer looks like it's answering something completely unrelated. If you have an RTE9, you're accessing an array or collection with an illegal index. And why are you making two loops anyway - you already have a 2D array that contains everything you need. Make one loop and extract a function instead of copy-pasting code like this. If you want to ask about RTE9, provide a [mcve] and specify exactly which instruction is causing the error.

Comment: @Mat'sMug that's why i am asking how can I make it one loop and what you mean by extract a function

Comment: @user3713336 this answer tells you exactly how you can make it one loop.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I am using instr, I don't think i can use it at instr----firstdash = InStr(1, dText(i, 1), "-")

Comment: @Mat'sMug any idea on this one-----https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48675064/finding-largest-number-and-deleting-remaining-smallest-number

Answer (score 0):

I ended up defining another loop. That's how I did it, before i was trying to do it in one loop but didn't work.

```
 Set rngText = wSheet3.Range(wSheet3.Range("A1"), wSheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
 Set rngText2 = wSheet3.Range(wSheet3.Range("B1"), wSheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
 dText = rngText.Value
 dText2= rngText2.Value

         For i = 1 to Ubound(dText,1)
            'do stuff

         Next i
          'second loop
         For ii = 1 to Ubound(dText2,1)
             'do stuff

         Next ii
```