# Finding largest number and deleting remaining smallest number

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to Delete cell by comparing Names within the same column, If I find the same name, Then make sure name is containing bigger number after forward
slash, If I find the bigger number then make sure my C column matching my criteria (NOT Playing). If it is matching then delete all cell which is a smaller number with column c saying Still Playing and keep only bigger number which is saying Not Playing. Any Ideas, I have posted my code but when I am finding a bigger number, it's going back and comparing with another cell so it's coming back to the same number. Here is my code..

```
Sub xm()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long, firstD As Integer, secondD As Integer
    Dim firstForward As Integer
    Dim secondForward As Integer, score1 As String, score2 As String
    Dim fName As String, sName As String
    lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

      For i = 2 To lastrow

          firstD = InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), "/")
          fName = Left(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), firstD - 1)
          secondD = InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1), "/")
          sName = Left(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 1), secondD - 1)

              If fName = sName Then
                 firstForward = InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1), "/")
                 score1 = Mid(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4), firstForward + 1)
                 secondForward = InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4), "/")
                 score2 = Mid(ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4), firstForward + 1)

                   If score1 > score2 Then
                      If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) = "Not Playing" Then
                      'Delete entire cell
                      End If

                   End If
              End If
       i = i + 1
      Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Output:---

[image]

Comment: Can you include an example of expected output for the given input?

Comment: What's the question? Have you tried stepping through the code? Set a breakpoint (F9), run the code, and when the breakpoint is hit use F8 to run instructions one by one; use the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G) and the `?`/`Print` instruction to evaluate expressions in break mode, and use the *Locals* toolwindow to inspect everything in scope. If the question is about conditionally deleting rows, that's been answered a hundred times over already.

Comment: Its not deleting only rows, its deleting rows if the number is bigger and matching with column C

Comment: @Mat'sMug I worked on it and i did this part but not working giving me an error invalid qualifer----  
                If rev > rev2 Then
                    rev2.EntireRow.Delete
                Else
                   rev.EntireRow.Delete
                 End If

Comment: *If the question is about **conditionally deleting rows**, that's been answered a hundred times over already.* - if your question is about a specific error (as it *should be*), then [edit] your post to include a [mcve] and tell us about it.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I didn't find anything regarding this question ... I am trying to find the bigger number then match column c and then delete smaller number